# Is the empty string a valid lambda expression?

Tags: logic, lambda-calculus

My first intuition is yes, because the empty string is usually a valid instance of whatever object. There's usually good conceptual reasons for this. But in lambda calculus, I believe the standard definition allows three types; variables, abstractions, and application. And none of these allow for being empty.

Answer (score 2):

No, for exactly the reason you gave.